# Cross-sum operation in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there any efficient way to do cross-sum operation in matlab. Given two sets A and B, the cross-sum is the pairwise addition of vectors from A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

```
a=[1 2 3;4 5 6]

b=[10 20 30; 40 50 60;70 80 90]

repmat(a, [size(b,1) 1]) + kron(b,ones(size(a,1),1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
a=[1 2 3 4]
b=[50 60 70 ]
bsxfun(@plus, a , b')
```

in GNU Octave or Matlab 2016b you can write:

```
a+b'
```

if elements of the set are vectors this is a possible solution:

```
a=[1 2 3;4 5 6]
b=[10 20 30; 40 50 60;70 80 90]
[A, B]= meshgrid(1:size(a,1), 1:size(b,1))
a(A,:) + b(B,:)
```

or

```
a={[1 2 3], [4 5 6]}
b= {[10 20 30],[40 50 60],[70 80 90]}
[A,B]=meshgrid(1:length(a),1:length(b))
cell2mat(a(A))+ cell2mat(b(B))
```

Comment: what if the set contains vectors?

Comment: @anup those vectors should be cross-summed?

Comment: Yes, the sets A and B contains vectors and the output should be the set of pairwise sum of vectors.

Comment: @anup so, length of vectors is the same?

Comment: Yes. the length of vectors are same

Comment: MATLAB R2016b .. is this a feature you found in the prerelease ?

Comment: @SomeGuy As a private message, I do not have any Matlab installation and sometimes rely on what i heard and on some blog posts https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/4n7oy9/r2016b_prerelease that implicit expansion (automatic broadcasting) added to r2016b prerelease!